# Complete Example Yaml program on http://code.google.com/p/yaml-cpp/wiki/HowToParseADocument does not compile

Tags: compilation, yaml-cpp

Using G++ 4.6.2 on Linux
Library was built according to instructions.  run_tests in test directory works fine.

setenv YAML_HOME /nfs/site/proj/dt/ltt_test_15/work_area/ironchef/new_version/ironchef/trunk/yaml/yaml-cpp-0.5.0

ls $YAML_HOME
total 640
 16 CMakeCache.txt         0 build/                 0 libyaml-cpp.so.0.5@      8 test/
  8 CMakeFiles/            8 cmake_install.cmake  480 libyaml-cpp.so.0.5.0*    8 util/
 16 CMakeLists.txt         0 include/               8 license.txt              8 yaml-cpp.pc
  8 CTestTestfile.cmake    8 install.txt            8 matt_sandbox/            8 yaml-cpp.pc.cmake
 40 Makefile               0 libyaml-cpp.so@        8 src/

cd matt_sandbox
g++ -o test_yaml -g -I/usr/intel/pkgs/boost/1.48.0-gcc-4.6.2/include -I$YAML_HOME/include -I$YAML_HOME/include/yaml-cpp -I$YAML_HOME/include/yaml-cpp/node -I$YAML_HOME/include/yaml-cpp/node/detail -I$YAML_HOME/include/yaml-cpp/contrib main.cpp

Compiler errors:
    main.cpp: In function `void operator>>(const YAML::Node&, Vec3&)':
    main.cpp:25: error: no match for 'operator>>' in 'YAML::Node::operator[](const Key&) const [with 
    ... similar errors ....
    main.cpp:51: error: 'class YAML::Parser' has no member named 'GetNextDocument'

Copy-and-paste code from complete example on http://code.google.com/p/yaml-cpp/wiki/HowToParseADocument

Answer (score 3, accepted):

That example uses the old API (version 0.3.0), but you're using the new API (version 0.5.0). I've updated the main page to make that clear.

For examples using the new API, see http://code.google.com/p/yaml-cpp/wiki/Tutorial.

Comment: Thanks, Jesse! That helped a lot.  Another thing that would help is if you could give a complete example for your new API (like you do for your old API).