# Attempt of a MWE of a yaml-cpp parser does not compile

Tags: yaml-cpp

I am using Ubuntu 20.04 with libyaml-cpp-dev (version 0.6.2-4ubuntu1).

I try to compile this simple example

```cpp
#include <iostream>
#include <yaml-cpp/yaml.h>

int main() {
    try {
        // Load YAML file
        YAML::Node config = YAML::LoadFile("example.yaml");

        // Access values in YAML file
        auto name = config["name"].as<std::string>();
        auto age = config["age"].as<int>();

        // Print parsed values
        std::cout << "Name: " << name << std::endl;
        std::cout << "Age: " << age << std::endl;

    } catch (const YAML::Exception& e) {
        std::cerr << "Error parsing YAML: " << e.what() << std::endl;
        return 1;
    }

    return 0;
}
```

with this `example.yaml` file

```yaml
name: Gandalf The Grey
age: 20
```

The compile command is `g++ yaml-parser.cpp -std=c++11 -lyaml-cpp -Wall -Werror -pedantic -o yaml-parser.x` and I obtain the following error:

```
/usr/bin/ld : /tmp/cczXm7sC.o : dans la fonction « YAML::Node::Scalar[abi:cxx11]() const » :
yaml-parser.cpp:(.text._ZNK4YAML4Node6ScalarB5cxx11Ev[_ZNK4YAML4Node6ScalarB5cxx11Ev]+0x7a) : référence indéfinie vers « YAML::detail::node_data::empty_scalar[abi:cxx11]() »
/usr/bin/ld : /tmp/cczXm7sC.o : dans la fonction « YAML::detail::node& YAML::detail::node_data::get<char [5]>(char const (&) [5], std::shared_ptr<YAML::detail::memory_holder>) » :
yaml-parser.cpp:(.text._ZN4YAML6detail9node_data3getIA5_cEERNS0_4nodeERKT_St10shared_ptrINS0_13memory_holderEE[_ZN4YAML6detail9node_data3getIA5_cEERNS0_4nodeERKT_St10shared_ptrINS0_13memory_holderEE]+0xd3) : référence indéfinie vers « YAML::detail::node_data::convert_to_map(std::shared_ptr<YAML::detail::memory_holder> const&) »
/usr/bin/ld : /tmp/cczXm7sC.o : dans la fonction « YAML::detail::node& YAML::detail::node_data::get<char [4]>(char const (&) [4], std::shared_ptr<YAML::detail::memory_holder>) » :
yaml-parser.cpp:(.text._ZN4YAML6detail9node_data3getIA4_cEERNS0_4nodeERKT_St10shared_ptrINS0_13memory_holderEE[_ZN4YAML6detail9node_data3getIA4_cEERNS0_4nodeERKT_St10shared_ptrINS0_13memory_holderEE]+0xd3) : référence indéfinie vers « YAML::detail::node_data::convert_to_map(std::shared_ptr<YAML::detail::memory_holder> const&) »
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
```

I tried compiling it, narrowing the problem. It seems it's the `config["name"]` that blocks compilation. Am I doing something wrong? As already mentionned [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/14366748/1879269), the wiki lacks a complete example.

Comment: 1. You might try using a more recent version than 0.6.2

Comment: 2. This usually means your installation wasn’t correct, not your code. Your code looks fine. Check if you have two versions installed or something.

Comment: Thanks! I just checked in another computer with Ubuntu 22.04 and it works well. I'll have a look on the first one. I tried to use the git repo and might have forgot to remove something.